# Как создать выбор формы через radio input?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Всем привет!

Есть три формы: пополнение счета через PayPal, QIWI и Яндекс Деньги. Пользователю предлагается выбрать один из методов через radio input. Проблема в том, что для этих методов оплаты разные form запроса.

Пример формы выбора оплаты:

```
<form id="check" action="">
 <input type="radio" value="paypal">
 <input type="radio" value="qiwi">
 <input type="radio" value="yandex">
</form>
```

Пример самих форм оплаты:

```
<form id="paypal" action="paypal.com">
 <input type="hidden' name=paypal>
</form>
<form id="qiwi" action="qiwi.com">
 <input type="hidden' name=qiwi>
</form>
<form id="yandex" action="yandex.com">
 <input type="hidden' name=yandex>
</form>
```

**Собственно вопрос - как сделать форму для выбора формы?)**

Благодарен за любую помощь или направление!

Comment: А зачем разные формы, если можно просто подменять атрибут `action` у одной формы? и имя у hidden поля тоже

Comment: значение input и их количество разное для всех форм. Формы привел для примера

Comment: Типа таб-выбора. Ставьте на радио-кнопку событие и по нему меняйте содержиоме формы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// выбор всех форм
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('form#check input[type=radio]');

// при клике на кнопку, берется её значение,
// прячутся все остальные формы и показывается конкретная с 
// переданным идентификатором
forms[0].addEventListener("click",function(e) {  
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "INPUT") {
    hideFormsButFirst();
    setFormVisible(e.target.value);    
 }
});

// функция, которая прячет все формы, кроме той, где радио кнопки
function hideFormsButFirst() {
  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; ++i) {
    forms[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  forms[0].style.display = 'block';
}

// отображает форму по переданному идентификатору
function setFormVisible(id = "paypal") {
    var form = document.getElementById(id);         
    form.style.display = 'block';                              
}

// первоначальные заготовки
function init() {
    hideFormsButFirst();
    setFormVisible();
}

init();
```

```html
<form id="check" action="">
 <input type="radio" value="paypal" name="payment" checked=checked>
 <input type="radio" value="qiwi" name="payment">
 <input type="radio" value="yandex" name="payment">
</form>

<form id="paypal" action="paypal.com">
 <input type="hidden" name=paypal>
  paypal форма
</form>

<form id="qiwi" action="qiwi.com">
  qiwi форма
 <input type="hidden" name=qiwi>
</form>
<form id="yandex" action="yandex.com">
  yandex форма
 <input type="hidden" name=yandex>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Благодарен за любую помощь или направление!

Вар1. Использовать один action и, передавая в него имя/метку вида платежа производить нужные действия.

Вар2. Использовать 2 формы (первая только выбор без отправки) и вторую подгружать js-om с нужными action.

Вар3. Менять непосредственно action по js.